# Couldn't find Wiki without an ID error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a wiki clone app in ruby on rails and I am trying to destroy a wiki, however after I click on the destroy link I get this error:

```
Couldn't find Wiki without an ID
```

and it has problems with this code block

```
def destroy
@wikis = Wiki.all
@wiki = Wiki.find(params[:wiki_id])
@collaborator = @wiki.users.find(params[:user_id])
authorize @wiki
end
```

where I call the delete function is in my wiki#views file. The link looks like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete Wiki", @wiki, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger', data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this wiki?' } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused by the following line:

```
@wiki = Wiki.find(params[:wiki_id])
```

`params[:wiki_id]` is `nil`. So essentially you're doing this:

```
@wiki = Wiki.find(nil)
```

In which case `find` will throw the error you're seeing, since it cannot find records with an ID of `nil`.

As per tadman's suggestion, try changing the line to the following:

```
@wiki = Wiki.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: It's typically `params[:id]` except for nested routes.